# How to (not?) thumbprint AWS OIDC provider rotating certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-iam

As explained here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html AWS OIDC providers require you to whitelist the HTTPS certificate from the OIDC endpoint with a fingerprint.

The issue I am facing is that my AWS OIDC provider stops working whenever the identity provider legitimately rotates their certificate. This happens relatively often.

So, a mitigation that is explained in those docs is to fingerprint CA's certificates instead of the final HTTPS cert. Yet, as far as I understand, fingerprinting the CA's intermediate signing cert could still break my AWS OIDC provider when the CA rotates their operative intermediate cert. This happens every few years.

Then, fingerprinting either the root or the intermediate CA certificates could still break the thing if the identity provider ever changes their CA of choice. This could happen any time.

Multiple fingerprints are permitted by AWS, precisely to handle certificate rotation. But how I am supposed to fingerprint third parties future certificates before they are deployed and already break my AWS OIDC integration?

**What is a canonical solution for this?**

In the docs there is a note saying that

> AWS secures communication with some OIDC identity providers (IdPs) through our library of trusted certificate authorities (CAs) instead of using a certificate thumbprint to verify your IdP server certificate. These OIDC IdPs include Google, and those that use an Amazon S3 bucket to host a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) endpoint. In these cases, your legacy thumbprint remains in your configuration, but is no longer used for validation.

The external OIDC provider effectively serves a JWKS endpoint linked in the standard `.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint, so ideally I'd like to use this. Yet, this is being utterly ignored by AWS because... the third party JWKS endpoint is not hosted in AWS S3??. What am I supposed to do with that at all?

---

Known unsolvable issues:

- https://github.com/calidae/terraform-aws-bitbucket-oidc/issues/1
- https://github.com/terraform-module/terraform-aws-gitlab-oidc-provider/issues/25
- https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/aws/configure-openid-connect-in-aws/-/issues/3
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/392713
- https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/669

---

**Update**

As the aftermath of yet another mass breakage https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-27-github-actions-update-on-oidc-integration-with-aws/ the AWS IAM team has released an exception so that github.com (not GH Enterprise Servers, not GitLab, not any other valid OIDC provider) is exempt from the certificate pinning nonsense (but a dummy fingerprint is still required): https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/357#issuecomment-1626357333

So, this demonstrates a non-canonical solution is being in the GAFAM lobby and pushing GAFAM siblings to make exceptional accommodations for your users instead of fixing their systems for everyone.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html - you can add more than one thumbprint, one for the old certificate, one for the new, then you rotate the certificate and everything should work without interuption.

Comment: I can't fingerprint future certificates until they are deployed, already breaking the integration. Will update the question.

Comment: Why not? You just need the certificate file, it does not need to be deployed on any server for that to work.

Comment: Because I do no operate the external OIDC service. Name one third party API that notifies you future TLS certificate deployments. The whole point of using CA chains of trust is to avoid this!

Comment: Workaround: host the provider's JWKS in your own bucket with automation that updates your bucket copy when provider updates theirs.

Comment: I thought about that, but the JWKS URL is linked in `https://example.com/oidc-endpoint/.well-known/openid-configuration` in a `jkws_uri` key of the response data. So that would mean the whole OIDC provider API has to be reverse proxied and responses should be tampered to replace any absolute URL. I believe it would work but... damn.

Comment: I don't see GitHub listed under AWS' library of trusted CAs. Does that mean OIDC integrations with GitHub will be similarly effected?

Comment: I understand so. But here DigiCert's operative intermediate certificate used to issue the `*.actions.githubusercontent.com` certificate will not expire until 13th April 2031 so everything should work for a long time unless DigiCert has some kind of incident and needs to rotate their operative cert before that deadline. Related issue: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/357